# Replace part of cell with something else for a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date in the form DD-MMM-YY and I need to replace the English months (MMM) with the German ones (my Excel is in German). I found this code on the Microsoft dev page:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _ 
 What:="SIN", Replacement:="COS", _ 
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True`

which I adjusted to my needs as follows:

`Worksheets("export0").columns("J").Replace _
 What:="DEC", Replacement:="DEZ", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True`

However, when running it, Excel shows me a pop-up asking for the name of the makro and it does not allow me to execute it. Would anyone be able to provide some guiding on this?

Comment: If your subroutine requires a parameter (or parameters) to be passed through it you will not be able to simply run it without providing these parameters, unless they are optional.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've provided. You need to show more code including the declaration; e.g. **Sub MyMacro()**. Could you be in Debug Mode or Macro Recording mode? You cannot run a sub in these environments.

Comment: It may also be the case that your date is a "real date" and displayed in English due to your windows regional settings or formatting.  If that is the case, the solution will be different.